# what I want as output is the smallest positive value that can be evenly divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

```
import java.util.*;
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int smallest_positive_number,i,count,rem;
        
        count =0;
        for(smallest_positive_number=1;smallest_positive_number<2147483647; smallest_positive_number++){
            for(i=1; i<=20; i++){
                rem=smallest_positive_number%i;
                if(rem==0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count==20){
                System.out.print(smallest_positive_number+" is the smallest value that is evenly divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20");
            }
            count=0;
            
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to find the smallest positive value that can be evenly divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20. I can't find any error and it doesn't show any compile time error. But it doesn't give any output in runtime. I want to know the error please?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It seems to mostly work (I get the correct first result), but: it doesn't stop after the first result, and it is insanely ineffective (on my computer it needs 28 seconds where a slightly more efficient version takes less than a second). Using the windows calculator is faster than using your program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is much help, but if you add 'break' after your 'System.out' it works alright but is still quite slow.

```
if(count==20){
                System.out.print(smallest_positive_number+" is the smallest value that is evenly divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20");
                break;
            }
```

Hope it was somewhat useful.